# iOS - Runtime Dynamic Class not key-value coding compliant

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, key-value-coding

I've been getting up to speed on Dynamic Class creation at runtime in Objective-C and have hit an issue I can't quite seem to work around. After a good deal of searching around, I'm still puzzled.

The issue here is making a:

```
[runtimeClassInstance setValue:age forKey:@"age"];
```

call to an object instantiated from:

```
id runtimeClassInstance = [[NSClassFromString(@"Employee") alloc] init];
```

Which was created by

```
[NewClassMaker buildClassFromDictionary:@[@"FirstName", @"LastName",\
                                          @"Age", @"Salary"]
                               withName:@"Employee"];
```

This is croaking with an *NSUnknownKeyException:this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key age* error.

If I use the following invocation approach, things work just fine:

```
SEL setAgeSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"setAge");
NSInvocation *call = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[[NSClassFromString(@"Employee") class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:setAgeSelector]];
call.target = runtimeClassInstance;
call.selector = setAgeSelector;
NSNumber *age = @(25);
[call setArgument:&age atIndex:2];
[call invoke];
```

Now that static method to create the class is as such:

```
+(NSDictionary*)buildClassFromDictionary:(NSArray*)propNames withName:(NSString*)className
{
    NSMutableDictionary* keys = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    Class newClass = NSClassFromString(className);

    if(newClass == nil)
    {
        newClass = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], [className UTF8String], 0);

        // For each property name, add a new iVar, getter, and setter method for it.
        for(NSString* key in propNames)
        {
            NSString* propName = [self propName: key];
            NSString* iVarName = [self ivarName:propName];

            class_addIvar(newClass, [iVarName UTF8String] , sizeof(NSObject*), log2(sizeof(NSObject*)), @encode(NSObject));

            objc_property_attribute_t a1 = { "T", "@\"NSObject\"" };
            objc_property_attribute_t a2 = { "&", "" };
            objc_property_attribute_t a3 = { "N", "" };
            objc_property_attribute_t a4 = { "V", [iVarName UTF8String] };
            objc_property_attribute_t attrs[] = { a1, a2, a3, a4};

            class_addProperty(newClass, [propName UTF8String], attrs, 4);
            class_addMethod(newClass, NSSelectorFromString(propName), (IMP)getter, "@@:");
            class_addMethod(newClass, NSSelectorFromString([self setterName:propName]), (IMP)setter, "v@:@");

            [keys setValue:key forKey:propName];
        }

        Class metaClass = object_getClass(newClass);
        // This method is returning NO on purpose to find out why there is no key.
        class_addMethod(metaClass, @selector(accessInstanceVariablesDirectly), (IMP)accessInstanceVariablesDirectly, "B@:");

        // Auxilliary methods added to the new class instance so the accessor dynamic methods above can work.
        // Not sure if the initial impl of this class maker class worked.
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(ivarName:), (IMP)ivarNameForString, "@@:@");
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(propName:), (IMP)propNameForString, "@@:@");
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(propNameFromSetterName:), (IMP)propNameFromSetterNameString, "@@:@");

        // Add a customized description dynamic method to this class. It will dump out any list of properties added
        // to the object during init here.
        Method description = class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class],
                                                     @selector(description));
        const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(description);

        // now add
        class_addMethod(newClass, @selector(description), (IMP)Description, types);
        objc_registerClassPair(newClass);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

There are three possibilities here that I am stewing over:

1. I have missed some crucial step here to get these properties and
   their dynamic accessors working in a key-value compliant fashion
2. If I do allow direct iVar access, is the retain for the value not
       happening?
3. Is the NSInvocation approach the best way?

Comment: Is the name of the setter method `setAge` or `setAge:`?

Comment: The NSInvocation call does in fact expect to call the 'setAge' setter method sans the trailing colon. It is the subsequent call to [setArgument:atIndex:] that captures the value and properly assembles the setter signature.

Comment: @MartinStoufer Would you mind sharing the full source code for that issue. I'm having a hard time passing the same exception. Also what is propName and ivarName functions that you are calling what does they do? There also a couple of functions that you are calling and I've no idea what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setter method is named `setAge`. `setValue:forKey:` searches for `setAge:` with a colon. Add a colon at the end of the name of the setter method. In Objective-C the colons are part of the method names.

Comment: Almost there. Adding an kvo observer and changing the key to `setAge:` still results in an _*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Employee 0x100201f30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key setAge:.'_ being thrown.

Comment: Change the name of the setter method to `setAge:`, the key is `Age`. [Accessor Search Patterns for Simple Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-SW1)

Comment: Yeah, still no go. I think that the behind the scenes subclassing by KVO is destroying something with this runtime class. I've tested a few combinations  with this different key value and they all crash in like manners. I'll tidy things up and post a link here to the project on Git. Everyone is welcome to examine it see what they find.

Comment: Oh, finally! @Willeke's suggestion, while not the final answer, did put me back on the right track. The KVO key is just `age`, but I needed to modify the setter methods to include the colon. Once I figured that out and dropped some apparently invalid code (the KVO observer method no longer calls its super impl as Apple docs require). I've checked in my changes. I hope everyone gets some milage out of this example. Improvements & suggestions always welcome